# "How long" in a question

Tags: meaning, questions

> How long does it take for my item to arrive?
>
> How long does it take to arrive?

Could the second question be used as an alternative to the first? Should I provide some context before utilizing it?

But what if I add "will" instead of "does"? Will the meaning remain unchanged?

> How long will it take for my item to arrive?
>
> How long will it take to arrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both the use of “will” and “does,” it is ok to  leave out the phrase “for my item” if it has context in a previous sentence.

> I recently purchased a refrigerator at this store. How long will it take to arrive?

The “it” is in reference to the refrigerator in the previous sentence.